# How to concat JSON objects from different URLs with nested resources

Tags: angularjs, json, angular-promise, angular-http

```
///Returning JSON 1
$http.get("url1").
   then(function (response) {
       $scope.foo = response.data;
});

///Returning JSON 2
$http.get("url2").
   then(function (response) {
       $scope.foo = response.data;
});

///Returning JSON (n)
$http.get("n").
   then(function (response) {
       $scope.foo = response.data;
});
```

Can I somehow concat these JSON objects into one? The reason is that I have ALOT of data and since I rather would like to display alot of data for the user to filter through than to have them click through 1000 pages in a SPA, I would like to join them if that's possible (in a reasonable manner ofcourse).

**EDIT**

I was thinking something like this

```
var url ="";

for (... i < 100...) {
    url = "http://url.com"+i+"";
    $http.get(url).
        then(function(response){
           $scope.foo.concat(response.data);
           }
        );
}
```

**Update**

I've managed to join the JSON returns into an array of objects. But the problem is that this array now contains objects which in itself contains an object which in itself contains an array of objects... yup!

Answer (score 3):

If it's array then you can concat it.

Initialize empty array first

```
$scope.foo = [];

$http.get("url1").
   then(function (response) {
       $scope.foo.concat(response.data);
});
```

Comment: But I have alot of different urls that I would need to loop through, since they only have the page number differentiating them.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to create a promise that returns an array:

```
function arrayPromise(url, max)
    var urlArray = [];
    for (let i=0; i<max; i++) {
        urlArray.push(url + i);
    };
    var promiseArray = [];
    for (let i=0; i<urlArray.length; i++) {
        promiseArray.push($http.get(urlArray[i]);
    };
    return $q.all(promiseArray);
});
```

To fetch nested arrays, chain from the parent:

```
function nestedPromise (url, max) {
    var p1 = arrayPromise(url + "item/", max);

    var p2 = p1.then(function(itemArray) {
        var promises = [];
        for (let i=0; i<itemArray.length; i++) {
            var subUrl = url + "item/" + i + "/subItem/";
            promises[i] = arrayPromise(subUrl, itemArray[i].length);
        };
        return $q.all(promises);
    });
    return p2;
};
```

Finally resolve the nested promise:

```
nestedPromise("https://example.com/", 10)
  .then(function (nestedArray) {
    $scope.data = nestedArray;
});
```

It is important to use a `return` statement at all levels of the hierarchy: in the `.then` methods and in the functions themselves.

---

### *Chaining promises*

*Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.*

*It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.*

*[— AngularJS $q Service API Reference - Chaining Promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)*

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks. Never would've found that by just a quick glance at the angular documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can wait for the n requests to finish and then do whatever you want with the object returned.

```
$q.all($http.get("url1"), $http.get("url2"), $http.get("url3"))
  .then(function (responses) { 
  // This function is called when the three requests return.
  // responses is an array with the first item being the result of
  // fetching url1, the second fetching url2, etc.

  // Depending on what the response looks like you may want to do
  // something like:

  $scope.data = angular.merge(responses[0], responses[1] /* etc */);
});
```